# Getting error message call to undefined function on Laravel relation

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, eloquent-relationship

I am working on a query in Laravel 8 project for retrieving company details. Below is the structure and MySQL query.

```sql
# Getting company param from request.

SELECT c.company_name, p.position_name, s.salary
FROM tbl_company as c
JOIN tbl_company_type as t ON t.id = c.company_type_id
JOIN tbl_company_position as p ON p.company_id = c.id
JOIN tbl_comapny_salary as s ON s.position_id = p.id
where c.id = 1
```

Table structure:

| tbl_company_type |
| --- |
| id |
| type |
| description |

| tbl_company |
| --- |
| id |
| company_type_id |
| company_name |
| description |

| tbl_company_position |
| --- |
| id |
| position_name |
| company_id |

| tbl_comapny_salary |
| --- |
| id |
| position_id |
| salary |

**Company Models**

```
 namespace App\Models;

 use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
 use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Company extends Model
{
protected $table = 'tbl_company';

public function listtype()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Type::class, 'id', 'company_type_id');
}

 public function listposition()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Type::Position, 'company_id', 'id');
}
}


namespace App\Models;

 use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
 use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

 class Type extends Model
 {
  protected $table = 'tbl_company_type';
 }



 namespace App\Models;

 use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
 use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

 class Position extends Model
 {
 protected $table = 'tbl_company_position';

 public function listsalary()
 {
    return $this->hasOne(Type::Salary, 'position_id', 'id');
 }
 }


  namespace App\Models;

  use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
  use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

  class Salary extends Model
  {
  protected $table = 'tbl_comapny_salary';
  }
```

Retrieving comany details using relation

```
   $companydetails = Company::with('listtype', 'listposition','listsalary')- 
  >whereRaw("tbl_company = 2")->get();
```

Getting this error

> message": "Call to undefined relationship [listsalary] on model
> [App\Models\Position]

Comment: Not sure, but, i think the error is coming because the relationship listsalary is declared on the Position Model and you are trying to access it from the Company Model

Comment: But I think you're calling the relationship method in the Company model, if you want to load that, I think you have to rewrite like ``$companydetails = Company::with('listtype', 'listposition.listsalary')- 
  >whereRaw("tbl_company = 2")->get();``, since the Position is the one with that relationship

Answer (score 0):

Your company model doesn't have any **listsalary** relationship.

```php
class Company extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'tbl_company';

    public function listtype() 
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Type::class, 'id', 'company_type_id');
     }

    public function listposition()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Type::Position, 'company_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

When you are calling **Company::with()** you are calling the relations within that Company Model only. To access listsalary you can do

```php
   $companydetails = Company::with('listtype','listposition','listposition.listsalary')- 
  >whereRaw("tbl_company = 2")->get();

// or 

   $companydetails = Company::with([
      'listtype',
      'listposition' => function ($query) { 
          $query->with('listsalary'); // $query is your listposition relation
     }

   ])
  ->whereRaw("tbl_company = 2")->get();
```

Should definitely have a better naming convention.

Comment: Sidenote, you don't need both `'listposition', 'listposition.listsalary'`, just `'listposition.listsalary'`; that will include `listposition` and `listsalary` :)